# error after clean install

Tags: wordpress, error, install

after running the install script it redirects to a blank screen.
On phpmyadmin appears that the db is installed correctly.
wordpress error give the folowing error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\LazyProxy\PhpDumper\NullDumper' not found in /var/www/html/organisatie/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Dumper/PhpDumper.php:172
Stack trace: 
#0 /var/www/html/organisatie/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Dumper/PhpDumper.php(620): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Dumper\PhpDumper->getProxyDumper()
#1 /var/www/html/organisatie/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Dumper/PhpDumper.php(680): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Dumper\PhpDumper->addService('angular', Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition))
#2 /var/www/html/organisatie/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Dumper/PhpDumper.php(154): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Dum in /var/www/html/organisatie/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Dumper/PhpDumper.php on line 172
```

Comment: What version of CiviCRM are you using?  Did you follow the installation guide here: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/install/wordpress/ ?

Comment: I'm running: Civicrm 5.3.1  on wordpress 4..9.8  The  only other plugins: Akismet and  hallo Dolly. And yes, I folowed  the install instructions.